# Discard White Stone of Ancients to activate effect

Tags: yu-gi-oh

> Once per turn, during the End Phase, if this card is in the GY because it was sent there this turn: You can Special Summon 1 "Blue-Eyes" monster from your Deck.

That's the effect of The White Stone Of Ancients, so I'm not sure if I can use a card to discard it and then activate its effect, or if I need a card that's says "Send to the GY"

Update: Yeah, I know, what I am asking is, if after discarding it with the effect of another card (let's say, Dragon Ravine), can I activate White Stone of Ancients's effect? Because I sent it to the graveyard by discarding it, but I'm not sure if it works like that or I need to sent it there by using a card that says "Send to the GY"

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the effect in the End Phase if you send White Stone of Ancients (WSoA) to the Graveyard by some means throughout your turn.

---

In your question you mention [Dragon Ravine](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ravine)

> Once per turn: You can discard 1 card, then activate 1 of these effects;
>
> ● Add 1 Level 4 or lower "Dragunity" monster from your Deck to your hand.
>
> ● Send 1 Dragon monster from your Deck to the GY.

As discarding a card implicitly sends it to the Graveyard you gain use the effect of WSoA if you discard it for Dragon Ravine's cost, or if you send it to the Graveyard as part of its effect.

Other means of getting WSoA out of your hand to use it's effect in the End Phase could be a card like [Cards of Consonance](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Cards_of_Consonance)

> Discard 1 Dragon Tuner with 1000 or less ATK; draw 2 cards.

or you can summon it and link summon into Linkuriboh.

Answer (score 0):

No. The ability on [The White Stone of Ancients](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/The_White_Stone_of_Ancients) does not allow you to discard it just to get it into the graveyard, you need some other way to get it there.

he ways that a card can be sent to the graveyard, by Yu Gi Oh's definition of sent are, tribute (including materials for ritual, syncro and link), destroy, discard detach and of course anything that specifically says send. Destroyed includes when it is by card effect or by battle. [Exchange of the Spirit](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Exchange_of_the_Spirit) does not send cards to the graveyard when it swaps the grave and deck, and cards like [Burial from a Different Dimension](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Burial_from_a_Different_Dimension) also don't send a card to the graveyard when they return it from banish.